# Can not push data to google firebase with react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, ecmascript-6, reactfire

I am using ReactJS (with ECMA6) and Google Firebase@3.0.3 and ReactFire@0.4.0 as middleware, but I can not get to push data to the firebase

---

```
import ReactFire from 'reactfire';
import Firebase from 'firebase';
let config = {
  apiKey: "apiKey",
  authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com"
};
Firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

---

when it comes to this:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let ref = Firebase.database().ref('/items');
    ReactFire.bindAsObject(ref, 'items');
  }
```

it gives me '**firebaseRef.ref is not a function**'

---

Comment: Where are you calling `firebaseRef.ref`?

Comment: You are not calling `firebaseRef.ref`

Comment: I am not calling `firebaseRef.ref`. I can not go any further, since it gives me this error: **Uncaught TypeError: firebaseRef.ref is not a function**

Comment: What should be the other step, since I could not find any solution or docs to that

Comment: Please note that current version of ReactFire (v1.0.0) doesn't work with ES6 since it's a mixin. https://github.com/firebase/reactfire/issues/38

Answer (score 0):

I found a different solution to this, without using Reactfire, but just the reference from source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference,

So after initializing the app from Google Firebase, there needs to be an auth, which should be firstly specified in the firebase app with a simple email and password, then:

```
Firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("email", "password").then(function (data) {

});
```

then from reference, I can add/update/remove data to firebase database

```
Firebase.database().ref('/items').push(
          {
            text: this.state.text,
            done: false
          }
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was facing the same issue, so i did a

```
npm install reactfire@ firebase@ --save
```

in admin mode, and tada , the errors vanished. My firebase Version: ^3.3.0 & reactfire Version: ^1.0.0